YouTube Studioの背景色を自作Chrome拡張機能で変えるには？
YouTube Studioの視聴数などを非表示にするChrome拡張機能を作りたく
ひとまず掲題のことをしたいです。色をかえるサンプルを実行して、DevToolsでは背景色がピンクにかわってるはずですが画面では変わりません。
DevToolsの要素
<body id="html-body" rounded-container="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 204, 204);"><script nonce="">if (window.ytcsi) {window.ytcsi.tick('ai', null, '');}</script><ytcp-app><!--css_build_scope:ytcp-app-->

他のサイトでは色を変えれています。
なにが足りないのでしょうか。
↓　document.body.style.backgroundColor = options.colorValue;のところで、自作拡張のオプションで保存したピンクで色を変えます
popup.js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", async () => {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: onRun,
  });
});

function onRun() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#fcc";
  chrome.storage.sync.get(null, (options) => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = options.colorValue;
  });
}


<body>の背景色は変更できているが、子孫要素で指定している背景色のせいで<body>の背景色は見えないのだと思います。
studio.youtube.com をざっと見る限り、<html> 要素に style="--ytcp-brand-background-solid: rgb(255, 204, 204);" を付ければ子孫要素の背景色を上書きできそうです。

DevToolsの要素に、教えて頂いた通りに書いてみたら上書きできました。ありがとうございます。次は視聴数などを非表示にしたいと思います。
